# Error: kafka umPeerMain

Tags: cygwin, apache-kafka

When I try to work on kafka in windows with cygwin and I'm getting below error, I'm not able to start any service. Could anyone suggest me how can I sort it out please?

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /cygdrive/c/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log due to No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726480/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-zookeeper-server-quorum-quorumpeerm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Kafka error on windows - Couldnot find or load main class QuorumPeerMain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037263/apache-kafka-error-on-windows-couldnot-find-or-load-main-class-quorumpeermain)